# Broken PHP page

Tags: php

I am trying to access this weapon store file and am getting a blank page. I was hoping someone could help me fix this. The link.php file is just a page holding images and is not the source of the problem as other pages calling on link work fine.

```
<?php
echo "<table width='100%'><tr><td valign='left' width='95%'><font size=2 color=silver><b>Weapon Market</b></font></td><td><table width=100%><tr><td align=right>";
include('../beta/files/link.php');
echo" Weapon Market. Users can come here to buy weapons that they can to to another city and sell at a black market for profit.'></a></td></tr></table><img src='/beta/layout_images/headertop.gif' width=100% height=4></center><br /><br />";
if(!isset($tools)){
echo"<font color=red><b>Error | It Seems Something Went Wrong Processing Your Account. Please Try Logging Out And Then Logging Back In. If The Problem Persists Please Email Support At Account@Steam-Wars.com. We Apologize For The Inconvenience.</b></font><br /><br /><center><img src='/beta/layout_images/headertop.gif' width=100% height=4></center><br />";
session_destroy();
exit();}        
        $qry    = 'SELECT * FROM weapons WHERE uid='.db_quote_smart($player->uid);
    $res    = db_query($qry);

    $has_weapons_array = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $weapon_names = array('bbgun_bullet', 'handgun_bullet', 'shotgun_bullet', 'rifle_bullet', 'bbgun', 'handgun', 'shotgun', 'ak47', 'bomb', 'taser', 'baseballbat', 'shank', 'detonator', 'battery');
    $name_hash = array(
        'bbgun_bullet'      => 'BBGun Bullet (4-9)',
        'handgun_bullet'    => 'Handgun Bullet (9-47)',
        'shotgun_bullet'    => 'Shotgun Bullet (28,142)',
        'rifle_bullet'      => 'Rifle Bullet (47-237)',
        'bbgun'             => 'BBGun (280-300)',
        'handgun'           => 'Handgun (470-500)',
        'shotgun'           => 'Shotgun (96-100)',
        'ak47'              => 'AK47 (415-500)',
        'bomb'              => 'Bomb (248-250)',
        'taser'             => 'Taser (45-50)',
        'baseballbat'       => 'Baseball Bat (90-100)',
        'shank'             => 'Shank (55-100)',
        'detonator'         => 'Detonator (427-475)',
        'battery'           => 'Battery (3-9)'
    );

    $qry    = 'SELECT * FROM prices_booze WHERE city='.db_quote_smart($player->city);
    $res    = db_query($qry);
    $prices = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $qry        = 'SELECT * FROM weapons WHERE uid='.db_quote_smart($player->uid);
    $res        = db_query($qry);
    $weapons    = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $limit  = $has_weapons_array["weapon_limit"];
    $space_used = 0;
    foreach($weapon_names as $name){
        $space_used += $weapons[$name];
    }
    $space_left = $limit - $space_used;

    $action = $_GVARS['action'];

    if( $action == 'buy' ){
        foreach($weapon_names as $weapon){

            $price  = $prices[$weapon];
            $amount = (isset($_POST[$weapon]) ? intval($_POST[$weapon]) : 0);
            $cost   = $price * $amount;

            if( $amount > 0 ){

                if( $gUser['cash'] < $cost ){
            echo"<font color=red><b>Error | You Do Not Have Enough Money To Purchase $amount unit(s) Of $weapon.</b></font><br /><br /><center><img src='/beta/layout_images/headertop.gif' width=100% height=4></center><br />";
                }elseif( ($space_left-$amount) < 0 ){
                        echo"<font color=red><b>Error | You Do Not Have Enough Space To Carry $amount unit(s) Of $weapon.</b></font><br /><br /><center><img src='/beta/layout_images/headertop.gif' width=100% height=4></center><br />";
                }else{
                    $space_left     -= $amount;
                    $gUser['cash']  -= $cost;

                    $qry = 'UPDATE user_characters SET cash=cash-'.$cost.' WHERE uid='.db_quote_smart($player->uid);
                    $res = db_query($qry);

                    $randscam   = mt_rand(1, 100);
                    $randscam2  = mt_rand(1, 100);

                    if( $randscam == $randscam2 ){
                        echo"<font color=red><b>Error | You Were Scammed By A Dealer. The Weapons You Bought Turned Out To Be Replicas.</b></font><br /><br /><center><img src='/beta/layout_images/headertop.gif' width=100% height=4></center><br />";
                                                $randexp=rand(0,1);
                            $qry = 'UPDATE user_characters SET exp=exp+'.$randexp.', drug_points=drug_points+'.$amount.' WHERE uid='.db_quote_smart($player->uid);
                            $res = db_query($qry);
                    }else{
                        $qry = "UPDATE weapons SET $weapon=$weapon+$amount WHERE uid=".db_quote_smart($player->uid);
                        $res = db_query($qry);
                                                $randexp2=rand(1,2);
                            $qry = 'UPDATE user_characters SET exp=exp+'.$randexp2.', drug_points=drug_points+'.$amount.' WHERE uid='.db_quote_smart($player->uid);
                            $res = db_query($qry);
                                    $sql="UPDATE adv_stats SET drugs_bought=drugs_bought+$amount WHERE uid=".db_quote_smart($player->uid);
                                    $sql=mysql_query($sql);
                        echo"<font color=green><b>Ciao | You Have Purchased $amount Crate(s) Of $weapon.</b></font><br /><br /><center><img src='/beta/layout_images/headertop.gif' width=100% height=4></center><br />";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // gets updated version of weapons in pocket
    $qry    = 'SELECT * FROM weapons WHERE uid='.db_quote_smart($player->uid);
    $res    = db_query($qry);

    $has_weapons_array = mysql_fetch_array($res);       
echo "<table align=center width=100% bgcolor=000000><tr><td><br>";
echo "<table width='450' cellpadding='0' border='2' bordercolor='black' style='margin:0 auto;background-image: url(/beta/layout_images/bg_2.gif);'>
<tr bgcolor=#11111>
<td align=center>
<font face=verdana size=1 color=silver><b>Weapon</b></font>
</td>
<td align=center>
<font face=verdana size=1 color=silver><b>Cost</b></font>
</td>
<td align=center>
<font face=verdana size=1 color=silver><b># you have</b></font>
</td>
<td align=center>
<font face=verdana size=1 color=silver><b># to buy</b></font>
</td>
</tr>";

    $space_used = 0;
    $row = 0;
    foreach($weapon_names as $weapon){
        $space_used += $has_weapons_array[$weapon];
        echo('<tr bgcolor="#'.($row++ % 2 ? '444444' : '333333').'">
<td align="center" width="125"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color="#ffffff"><b><a href="javascript:popUp(\'weaponsmarket_graph_view.php?weapons='.$weapon.'\')">'.$name_hash[$weapon].'</a></b></td>
<td align="center" width="125"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color="#ffffff">$ '.number_format($prices[$weapon]).'</font></td>
<td align="center" width="125"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color="#ffffff">'.number_format($has_weapons_array[$weapon]).'</font></td>
<td align="center" width="125"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color="#ffffff"><form name="login" action="driver.php?x=weaponstore" method="post"><input type="text" name="'.$weapon.'" size=5 style="font-weight:none;font-size:8pt;color:#ffffff;font-family:arial;background-color:#000000;border-color:#ffffff" maxlength="15"></font></td>
</tr>');


echo "
</table>
<table width='450' cellpadding='0' border='2' bordercolor='black' style='margin:0 auto;background-image: url(/beta/layout_images/bg_2.gif);'>
<tr bgcolor=#11111 valign=top><td>
<table width=100%><tr>
<td align=left width=125><font face=verdana size=1 color=silver><input type=radio checked name=action value=buy> Buy </td>
<td align=center width=250><font size=1><font color=#FFFFFF><b>Weapon space:</b></font> " . $space_used . "/" . $has_weapons_array["weapon_limit"] . "</font></td>
<td align=right width=125><center><font face=verdana size=1 color=silver><input type=submit value=\"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Purchase Weapon&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\" style=\"FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR: #FFFFFF;  FONT-FAMILY: Arial; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #333333\" size=1></center></td>
</tr></table>
</td></tr>
</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Define "Broken Page" ?

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered by me and you deleted it...

As I said before there is no end bracket in last `foreach` !

```
foreach($weapon_names as $weapon){
    $space_used += $has_weapons_array[$weapon];
    echo('<tr bgcolor="#'.($row++ % 2 ? '444444' : '333333').'">
<td align="center" width="125"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color="#ffffff"><b><a href="javascript:popUp(\'weaponsmarket_graph_view.php?weapons='.$weapon.'\')">'.$name_hash[$weapon].'</a></b></td>
<td align="center" width="125"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color="#ffffff">$ '.number_format($prices[$weapon]).'</font></td>
<td align="center" width="125"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color="#ffffff">'.number_format($has_weapons_array[$weapon]).'</font></td>
<td align="center" width="125"><font face="tahoma" size="1" color="#ffffff"><form name="login" action="driver.php?x=weaponstore" method="post"><input type="text" name="'.$weapon.'" size=5 style="font-weight:none;font-size:8pt;color:#ffffff;font-family:arial;background-color:#000000;border-color:#ffffff" maxlength="15"></font></td>
</tr>');
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I deleted the initial question because you fixed page 1 so there was no need for that question anymore. Thank you Paul, both pages now work :)

Comment: @Firestar it may not be necessary for you, but the whole point of this site is to have a repository of questions and answers so that problems that have been solved don't have to be solved again.  Help out future readers by not deleting your questions once you get an answer.

Comment: @Watcher. You make a good point that I overlooked. I will not delete my questions anymore.